# Place Photo Requests with google api in img src

Tags: angularjs, google-places-api

I am trying to get list of location with their photos using google places api.
I am storing the response in a variable vm.locationList. In  my view I am iterating over this variable to show location list.
Following is the code

```
<div ng-repeat = "(key, value) in vm.locationList">
<div class="panel panel-primary">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="pull-left thumbnail">
        <span ng-if="vm.getPhotos">
        <img src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=150&photoreference={{value.photos[0].photo_reference}}&key=API_KEY" class="img-responsive" style="margin-right:10px;">
      </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <h4><b>{{value.name}}</b></h4>
      <p><i class="fa fa-map-marker" style="color:red"></i>&nbsp;{{value.vicinity}}</p>
      <p> open now: {{value.opening_hours.open_now}}</p>
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat = "type in  value.types">
      <p style="float:left;width:20%" class="tags">{{type}}<p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Now to get the photo I place http url request in src attribute of img tag. Though I am getting pics with the list but I see error in console saying bad request.
Following is the error I am getting in console

```
GET https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=150&photoreference={{value.photos[0].photo_reference}}&key=API_KEY 400 ()
```

And here is the http response

```
<title>Error 400 (Bad Request)!!1</title>

<a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>
<p><b>400.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
<p>Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I have got where I was doing mistake. I used Angular's ng-src in place of src attribute. Now its working fine. Binding was not working earlier. I got confused because even though binding was not working image was appearing.